# Visualizing complex function z1^n + z2^n = 1

Tags: python, numpy, complex-numbers, mayavi, cmath

I need to visualize this function `z1^n + z2^n = 1` using Python and Mayavi. Parametrization for this function is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import cmath as cm
from mayavi import mlab

e = np.e
pi = np.pi
n = 2
xi = 3
theta = np.mgrid[0:pi/2]
k1 = np.array([2,3])
k2 = np.array([0,1])
g = [0,1,2,3]

z11 = e**(((2*k1[0]*pi)/n)*1j) * (np.cos(theta*xi*1j))**(2/n)
z21 = e**(((2*k2[0]*pi)/n)*1j) * (np.sin(theta*xi*1j))**(2/n)


z12 = e**(((2*k1[0]*pi)/n)*1j) * (np.cos(theta*xi*1j))**(2/n)
z22 = e**(((2*k2[1]*pi)/n)*1j) * (np.sin(theta*xi*1j))**(2/n)


z13 = e**(((2*k1[1]*pi)/n)*1j) * (np.cos(theta*xi*1j))**(2/n)
z23 = e**(((2*k2[0]*pi)/n)*1j) * (np.sin(theta*xi*1j))**(2/n)

z14 = e**(((2*k1[1]*pi)/n)*1j) * (np.cos(theta*xi*1j))**(2/n)
z24 = e**(((2*k2[1]*pi)/n)*1j) * (np.sin(theta*xi*1j))**(2/n)

x11 = z11.real
x21 = z11.imag
x31 = z21.real

x12 = z12.real
x22 = z12.imag
x32 = z22.real

x13 = z13.real
x23 = z13.imag
x33 = z23.real

x14 = z14.real
x24 = z14.imag
x34 = z24.real

mlab.mesh(x11,x21,x31)
mlab.mesh(x12,x22,x32)
mlab.mesh(x13,x23,x33)

mlab.show()
```

I need to get a picture for n=2 that looks like this:

[image]

But I when I run my program mayavi scene shows nothing.

Comment: Nope still struggling with this, I don't usually work with python so this area is very unknown to me.

Comment: I have updated my code tho, I think I'm closer to the solution with this one

Comment: I keep getting this error now "AssertionError: Array x must be 2 dimensional." for line 45 --> mlab.mesh(x11,x21,x31)

Comment: @Silvio Where did you get that image? What are the axes and where are they?

Comment: Axes are x,y and z. Here you can see at the start of the video a picture that I screenshot http://services.foi.hr/mathematics/blender/OPM2017zadacaB.mp4

Comment: @BPL Problem is that I have to follow the given formula. However thank you for the help.

Comment: @BPL polynom2.py was just given in video as an example how the end result should look like. I don't have access to it.

Comment: @Silvio Did you finally solve this interesting problem, I've opened an issue on mayavi bug tracker but so far the question hasn't been solved. Take a look [here](https://github.com/enthought/mayavi/issues/645). Also, don't you have access to those pdfs? It'd be great to take a look to those